# WordPress Website Doesn't Open Up

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, web-hosting

I've configured a `WordPress` website and set up SSL certificate for that perfectly. Now after all are done, I am having this error every time and two browsers - Mozilla and Chrome: **The page isn’t redirecting properly** and **This page isn’t working XXXX.com redirected you too many times**. I've tried using the following in wp-config file but nothing works:

```
define('RLRSSSL_DO_NOT_EDIT_HTACCESS', true);
define('WP_HOME','https://XXXX.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://XXXX.com');
```

I am really worried about it and tried every possible way googling. Anyone could suggest the best way to solve it and would be glad to know.

**Update - 1**: Here is the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Update 2** - Again updated but still having the same issue:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Probably a problem with your .htaccess file

Comment: OK and thanks for the reply @j08691. So is there any way that I can deal with it? I am using a hosting service that provides one click set-up for the WordPress website. All are done like database, WordPress, SSL certificate but in vain.

Comment: You can post your .htaccess to your question so that someone can check it out and look for errors

Comment: Posted @j08691.

Comment: You probably only need the chunk after and including `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`

Comment: Anything wrong with the `.htaccess` file @j08691?

Comment: I'm not an expert in setting it up so I'll defer to those that know it better than I do

Comment: Could you open your developer console, go to the network tab and click the "preserve log" item, then go to your website. It should show you all locations it tries to redirect you too. The custom rule in the middle is non-standard and not needed afaik. Why do you have that rule there? What is RLRSSL thing you have in your config file? Is it from a plugin? Have you determined if that is the problem?

Comment: Could you please point out which rule do I've to remove @Sumurai8? I'll be removing the **RLRSSL** - I just used if works as a solution and not quite sure about it.

Comment: Refer [to the basic .htaccess file](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) that should work for any Wordpress site. Wordpress should already automatically redirect to the url you have in your `WP_SITEURL` variable (including protocol).

Comment: I've updated the `.htaccess` file but still having the issue @Sumurai8.

Comment: Have you checked in your developer console what is actually happening? Which urls is it looping between? What status codes are being used?

Comment: Never mind @Sumurai8. You mean developer console of the browser? I am giving the link here as well - https://rymacltd.com/ and it shows **302**.

Comment: Yes, the developer console of the browser. See my previous comment on how to figure out which urls it is visiting before the browser gives up.

Comment: It visits the same url @Sumurai8 and in the control panel, I've set it up like that I mean the redirect.

Comment: Do you have any Wordpress plugins that can cause a redirect to happen? Do you have any other rules in your .htaccess file? Do you have any rules in a static apache config file (e.g. httpd.conf?) As far as I can see all urls are being redirected to the main domain with https. If you are just using the default .htaccess file for Wordpress it does not originate there. At least not directly.

Comment: Remove htaccess and see if it works without it. Maybe its not that.